# Filter or action hook to insert content on admin pages before </body> tag

Tags: plugins, filters, admin, hooks, actions

I am developing an administrator plugin and want to be able to write some HTML content just before the last body tag . This content will initially be hidden then displayed with javascript when a user clicks on a button.

Can anybody advise if there are any action or filter hooks that I can leverage to insert this? Remember this is for admin pages not theme pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `admin_footer`, [`admin_footer-(hookname)`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_footer-%28hookname%29) or [`admin_footer-(plugin_page)`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_footer-%28plugin_page%29) actions.